# Forgot to add IPad storyboard and now Simulator is always running IPhone storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I created a XCode targeting IPhone, I've written a lot of code in the past weeks and now I need to add IPad storyboard(I forgot to create universal device...)

so I just added a new storyboard targeting ipad, gave a name to it, but every time I run the app calling the simulator, it calls the Iphone view instead

what am I missing?, I really don't want to create a new app a transfer all files to it

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you would need to change your project settings to universal. Then, you'd need to make the main storyboard file for iPad point to the correct place. After you do that, click on the right side of the bar that has your product's name (next to the stop button) and choose iPad x.x simulator.

Comment: "Then, you'd need to make the main storyboard file for iPad point to the correct place" this is where I am stuck, everything else I have done before, thanks

Comment: If you go to the summary portion of your project settings, and scroll down you'll see a section that says "iPad Deployment Info". There is then a Main Storyboard Drop Down input where you select the storyboard file that is for the iPad.